# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: <url>

Tags: java, urlconnection

I am trying to check if a service is available and always returns the same error:

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL

Internet browsing proposed that it was necessary to indicate the "USER-AGENT" and so I did, but the error remains the same:

```
openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla / 5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 40.0.2214.91 Safari / 537.36");
```

The complete code is:

```
url = cadenaURL + cadenaEndpoint;
URLConnection openConnection = new URL(url).openConnection();
openConnection.connect();
is = openConnection.getInputStream();
if ("gzip".equals(openConnection.getContentEncoding()))
    is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
```

and the error is in:

```
is = openConnection.getInputStream();
```

Someone could help me?

Thank You,
a greeting,

Comment: Try using a different string like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0)`

Comment: And are you sure you have authorization to the url?

Comment: What request method is the server expecting? A GET? A POST? A basic URLConnection will not send anything like this to the server - try something like Apache HttpClient maybe?

Comment: `403` means that you are forbidden to access the page. This could be for many reasons - not necessarily the user agent. It could be that you are supposed to have a cookie present from previous interaction but you are not sending it.

Comment: if the service refuses GET requests, change the HTTP method: `HttpURLConnection c = openConnection = new URL(url).openConnection(); c.setRequestMethod("POST or whatever");`

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to check if a service is available

Simply put returning 403 means the service is not available. There's your answer.

There's a possibility you're using the wrong url and attempting to connect to the wrong service.

However it seems also that

```
is = openConnection.getInputStream();
```

This may not be enough to connect to an HTTP server. You need to properly format the request, you need to show more of the code and how you're using it for us to help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I changed URLConnection by HttpURLConnection and works perfect.

Thank You